# Open/Show Activity when screen is locked?

Tags: android

In my reminder application if user set the reminder ,I can able to open a activity at the exact reminder time.But when the reminder arrives if screen is in locked mode after open the screen lock then only user can able to see my reminder screen.

But in the native alarm application is showing the snooze/Dismiss option even screen is in locked mode also.

how to do this in my application too.?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) `RTC_WAKEUP` type.

Answer (score 0):

use this.
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) Context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);